# Fresh download and start of Neo4j 2.1.5: fails to start

Tags: neo4j

1. I downloaded neo4j 2.1.5 for Mac
2. Extracted download and navigated into it
3. ./bin/neo4j start

Then I get...

Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [13916]... waiting for server to be ready.............................................................. Failed to start within 120 seconds.

**Message Log contents:** https://gist.github.com/kblake/c69287925cbd52bb3ffd

**Java info:**

22:23 $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

**Mac OS X 10.9.5**

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but there are related StackOverflow questions (related to JRMP startup) that strongly suggest this is some kind of networking issue on your machine.  Neo4j-shell uses RMI to do its thing, and it looks like your server is failing to set up the infrastructure for that due to a networking issue on your machine.  Something you might consider looking into.

Comment: I'm here to report that this question is invalid. I found out a third party app was interfering with network connectivity. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem and the comment you put is not so viewable !

The solution is to **turn off whatever is using the port 1337.**

For me it was https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-notification-reporter.

Cheers !

Comment: To find the PID: `lsof -i tcp:1337`